# SONAR: custom xpath-rule isn't available in plugin, but in MAVEN?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, rule

I created a new xpath-rule on my sonar-server and enabled it in a quality-profile.
When I start a maven-build with sonar:sonar this rule is used and violations are found.
When I start a local analyse inside Eclipse, the rule isn't used.
I found the pmd.xml in the workspace. In the pmd.xml used bei maven (workspace...\target\sonar) I see the rule:

```
<ruleset>
  <rule class="net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.XPathRule" message="don't use hardcoded userid" name="XPathRule_1372166528">
    <priority>2</priority>
    <properties>
      <property name="xpath">
        <value><![CDATA[//PrimaryPrefix 
 [(Literal[((matches(@Image,'^"[A,E][A-Z][0-9]{5}"$')) .... ])
 ]]]></value>**
      </property>
    </properties>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/strictexception.xml/AvoidRethrowingException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
.........
</ruleset>
```

In the pmd.xml used by the plugin (workspace ...\target\sonar-embedder-work) I can't find this rule. Does somebody know why this doesn't work and what can I do?

Thank you

Hedi

Comment: Which version of Sonar and Sonar Eclipse are you using ?